# where do I report usability bugs?

Tags: discussion

I have some beef with the way Ubuntu does some right click options a usability bug. Where do I report it? thanks!

Comment: This is about Ubuntu, not about Ask Ubuntu. It would belong on the main site, except it is a duplicate of many other questions...

Comment: If it's an Ubuntu question, ask it on Ask Ubuntu dot com. The meta site is about AskUbuntu.com itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bugs reports like that should go to Launchpad or better yet, the bug tracker for the project you're talking about (if that's different).

It can usually be asked by searching for the right thing but, a question of "Where do I file bugs for `<insert program here>?` is perfectly valid on the main site.